# Syncfusion Cannot render Grid rowtemplate expression value from dataSource

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

Hi I'm using Syncfusion Essential JS2 for JavaScript(ES5), and tryin' to use Grid Component to render data from this testdata array:

```
var testdata = [{firstName: 'Tony', lastName: 'Stark'}, {//some other objects}];
```

I created the Grid Object like this:

```
var grid = new ej.grids.Grid({
    dataSource: testdata,
    rowTemplate: '#row-template',
    columns: [
        {field: 'firstName', headerText: 'First Name'},
        {field: 'lastName', headerText: 'Last Name'}
    ],
});
grid.appendTo('#grid');
```

and the actual template script in my jsp looks like this:

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-template">
    <tr>
        <td>${firstName}</td> <!-- should render 'Tony' -->
        <td>${lastName}</td> <!-- should render 'Stark' -->
    </tr>
</script>
```

When i run it, td tags are blank,. it looks like '${}' syntax does **not** work,
then I tried putting hardcoded value inside td tags,

```
<td>Test First Name</td>
<td>Test Last Name</td>
```

and sure enough, hard coded values were successfully rendered. But I need to get the values from 'testdata' array..

I hope someone here have used Grid Components before. Please help me.
here are the technologies that i used:

Syncfusion Essential JS(ES5),
JSP,
Spring,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue.
The problem is that Syncfusion's templating engine and JSTL (JSP) templating engine has the same syntax:

```
${expression}
```

therefore, this script:

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-template">
<tr>
    <td>${firstName}</td> <!-- should render 'Tony' -->
    <td>${lastName}</td> <!-- should render 'Stark' -->
</tr>
```

because it's written inside a jsp file, ${firstName} and ${lastName} was rendered as if it's a JSTL expression. That's why td tags are blank.

to resolve this, i just moved the template code from jsp to my js file.

```
var grid = new ej.grids.Grid({
dataSource: testdata,
rowTemplate: '<tr><td>Write template code here</td></tr>',
columns: [
    {field: 'firstName', headerText: 'First Name'},
    {field: 'lastName', headerText: 'Last Name'}
],
});
grid.appendTo("#Grid");
```